# Quantum probability density of a uniformly accelerating charge

Tags: electromagnetism, reference-frames, charge, acceleration

Is the charge probability density of a uniformly accelerating charge any different than one that isn’t?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The wave function of a non accelerating charge charge stays put or moves at constant velocity. The wave function of an accelerating charge does not. The probability density of finding the charge at a particular location is more or less the square of the wave function. So yes, they will be different. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Title:] Quantum probability density of a uniformly accelerating charge

> Is the charge probability density of a uniformly accelerating charge any different than one that isn’t?

Yes, the functional form in a given frame will be different. This is true of the classical charge density, and also true of the "quantum probability density."

---

Also, your "one that isn't" can seemingly be performing any type of motion *other than* uniform acceleration. So your question seems vague in this respect.

---

The question of "uniform accelerat[ion]" is a little awkward in quantum mechanics, since we usually work with a Hamiltonian (energy) rather than working directly with forces.

For example, considering a constant external force such as $\vec F = F_0 \hat x$, results in the Hamiltonian
$$
\hat H =  \frac{\hat p^2}{2m} - F_0 x\;,
$$
which, unfortunately, is not positive definite, but nevertheless you [can find](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/the-surprisingly-simple-linear-potential-solution.286441/) solutions of the form:
$$
\psi(x,t) \sim e^{i(p+F_0t) x - i\frac{p^2}{2m} -\frac{ipF_0t^2}{2m}-\frac{iF_0^2t^3}{6m}}
$$

This can be compared to a solution of the free particle equation of the form:
$$
\psi_{\text{free}}(x,t)\sim e^{ipx-i\frac{p^2}{2m}t}
$$